# Fermi energy in Lithium

Tags: fermions, fermi-energy

In Fermi-Dirac statistic the number of states with energy between $[\epsilon,\epsilon+d\epsilon]$ is $dN=g(\epsilon)d\epsilon$ if I want to know the total number of occupied states in an atom I do this: $N=\int_{-\infty}^{\epsilon_f} g(\epsilon)d\epsilon$ where $\epsilon_f$ is the Fermi energy. Now, the number of electrons in the atom is $2N$ because of the spin. In the Lithium atom I have $3$ electrons: $2$ in the $1s$ state and $1$ in the $2s$ state, with the first integral I will obtain $N=3$ and so a total number of electrons equal to $4$ but the electrons in Lithium are only $3$. What's wrong?

Comment: Applying the solid state physics concept of a Fermi energy to an atom does not work.

Comment: Sometimes it does work, see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miedema%27s_model